# is there a way to set a coredata boolean property to allow only 1 object to be set to yes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i have a set of photos stored in coredata. in one particular tab (of a tab bar controller) i want to display a single selected photo. (photo selection is made in a different tab from a collectionview of photos). in coredata i have a boolean property for each photo named selectedPhoto. i want only 1 photo to ever have this boolean set to YES. if i select a new photo, is there a way to automatically switch the boolean property of the previously selected photo to NO. in other words is there a way to make a YES exclusive within a group of objects with a boolean property, where setting the boolean of one object to YES automatically switches it to NO for all other objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a BOOL attribute, use a relationship. Create a new entity with a 1:1 relationship to your `Photo` entity. Whenever the 'selected' photo is changed, set it into this relationship (which will cause the old connection to be broken).

This relationship could also be made with an existing entity instead of creating a new one...